# Define field in ndb using strings

Tags: python, google-app-engine, introspection

This is my code:

```
class SocialNodeSubscription(model.Model):
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    permissions=["post","read","reply","admin"]
    for p in permissions:
      self.__dict__["can_"+p]=model.BooleanProperty(default=True)
```

I need to dynamically define fields in my model but this doesn't seem to work because **dict** is not the right place where to put my fields.

For who don't know about ndb, this is how it would look like going the easier way.

```
class SocialNodeSubscription(model.Model):
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.can_write=model.BooleanProperty(default=True)
    self.can_read=model.BooleanProperty(default=True)
      ...
```

Edit:

Now my code looks like this:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    permissions=["post","read","reply","admin"]

    for p in permissions:
        self._properties["can_"+p]=model.BooleanProperty(default=True)        
     self._fix_up_properties()
```

But still i get this error.

> File "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\ndb\model.py", line
>   972, in _store_value
>       entity._values[self._name] = value TypeError: 'NoneType' object does not support item assignment

What does it mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's _properties,
just have a look at its metaclass MetaModel and class method _fix_up_properties.

Definition of _properties:

```
 # Class variables updated by _fix_up_properties()
 _properties = None
```

Method:

```
  @classmethod
  def _fix_up_properties(cls):
  """Fix up the properties by calling their _fix_up() method.

  Note: This is called by MetaModel, but may also be called manually
  after dynamically updating a model class.
  """
```

Comment: This looks fine but still doesn't work. Just edited the OP for another request.

Comment: Properties is initially set to be None. Try assigning `self._properties = {}` before your loop.

Answer (score 0):

Use an [expando model](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/entities#expando) for a model with dynamic properties.